# Alert when resources are scaled up (manual and auto) in Azure

Tags: azure

Is there a way that will help trigger an alert if recourses are scaled up in azure subscription? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can configure alerts based monitoring metrics for your Azure Services.
When you create an alert rule, you can select options to send an email notification to the service administrator and co-administrators or to another administrator that you can specify. A notification email is sent when the rule becomes active, and when an alert condition is resolved.

For websites go to the dashboard, select your website, click on the service plan and select the alert rules tile...
Add an alert based on the "Scale Up" Event. You can choose to email the owner and additional administrators.[image]

Comment: Thank you Aidan. I did not find 'service plan' for my resources. I guess I need to create one.

Comment: what type of resource is it ??

Comment: Its 'cloud services' .

Comment: yes, add a resource group and you should be able to configue the alert from the portal . Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi Aidan, The 'Add Alert' option was greyout under the Alert rules for the resource group. Does microsoft support this, or do I need to go to someother place to do this. Thanks again